# Attempting to use the lightning:notificationsLibrary is throwing a JS exception

Tags: lightning-aura-components

This was working fine a week or so ago. Now I recieve:

> Definition does not exist on the client for descriptor:markup://lightning:overlayInteropWrapper.

My markup:

```
    <lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifications" />
```

My controller function:

```
DisplayInfoWarningError : function(component, Level, Header, Message)
{
    var notifications = component.find("notifications");
    notifications.showNotice({
        "variant": Level.toLowerCase(),
        "header": Header,
        "message": Message });
}
```

Links to the lightning:notificationsLibrary in the online documentation are also broken.

Is anyone working with this currently?

Thanks in advance,
Jeff Clark

Comment: looks like google links are broken for most of the dev docs, but you can query directly from the online heplp portal --> https://help.salesforce.com/search#q=lightning:notificationslibrary&f:@sflanguage=%5Ben_US%5D&firstQueryMeta=%5Bobject%20Object%5D

Comment: are you using `lightning:notificationsLibrary` on a Lightning App ?

Comment: `lightning:notificationsLibrary` can only be used on Salesforce Context, Lightning App can work stand alone, outside the Salesforce Context, that's way you get the error